# How to delete OpenShift namespace?

Tags: openshift

In my local OpenShift instance based on CodeReady containers ( CRC ) I noticed that deleting a namespace is not a trivial task. Some namespaces will remain in "terminating" state indefinitely.

Using the command line I can try to force deletion of the namespace but this will only cause the oc client also only to start waiting indefinitely for deletion as shown below.

```bash
user@localhost:~$ oc delete namespace nodejs-helloworld-staging --force
warning: Immediate deletion does not wait for confirmation that the running resource has been terminated. The resource may continue to run on the cluster indefinitely.
namespace "nodejs-helloworld-staging" force deleted
```

Stop and start of the cluster does not cause OpenShift the proceed with the deletion of the namespace.

What is the correct way to delete namespaces completely? Is this supported by OpenShift? Or is this practice recommended against. Are there other approaches to make a namespace available? Is it for example possible / better / recommended to rename the namespace?

Now that I have a stuck "terminating" namespace, is it possible to get rid of it somehow? Is there a even more "forceful" way to "force" delete my namespace?

As a side question, why is namespace / project deletion such a difficult task to perform for OpenShift? Why is not trivial? Should it not be a trivial task.

Comment: you have to check why it is not deleted either by checking the 'oc get event' for that project of 'oc describe project name nodejs-helloworld-staging' and look for status 
It is always depending on other failed objects: PVC, cronjob...etc

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to **force** the deletion of a namespace (project on Openshift).

If you cannot gracefully delete the namespace, you can search for what OpenShift is stuck trying to delete in this namespace.

For example, use `oc get events` to get the OpenShift events and, after this, solve the problems which might appear.

Some resources might stop a namespace deletion, for example, a PVC. So you need to discover what is causing the problem when deleting the namespace. Also, prefer to use: `oc delete project <PROJECT NAME>`. You can also add a `--wait=true` flag.

Answer (score 0):

In OpenShit,`"namepsaces"`are linked to`"projects"`usually. To delete a `namespace`, delete the`project`with the same name

As for your problem of a`namespace`staying forever in the`terminating`state, there is a great chance that a dependent object is stuck somewhere being deleted by kubernetes

If you are sure of what you are doing, you can edit the`"project"`manifest and remove the`spec.finalizers`stanza. That will stop the"cascade delete" action